# How to save embedded object from Notes using C#?

Tags: c#, lotus-notes

Can someone guide me how to save an OLE embedded object `(Object Type -> EMBED_OBJECT)` from Lotus Notes using C#. I tired using NotesEmbeddedObject class from Interop.Domino, but could not find a suitable method to save it?

Thanks

RSP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, I think it is implied in the nature of OLE that there is no generalized way to do what you want.  Since the embedded storage format for an OLE object is not assumed to be the same as the standalone file storage format, the expectation is that you need to use the OLE server code to save the object to a file.  I.e., you should use the Activate method to invoke the OLE object's server, and then use the DoVerb method to tell the server to save the object as a file.  Of course, that doesn't help if the OLE server doesn't expose a Save verb, or if the OLE server is not installed on the machine where you are running.

Comment: In my case, NotesEmbeddedObject DoVerb method supports "&Edit" & "&Open" only. Any guidance on how should I go about?

Comment: Sorry, no idea how to proceed in a useful manner.  I'm sure you could use the Notes C API to get access to the data, but I have no idea if what you end up with will actually be useful.  This sort of thing is one of the reasons why I gave up on the idea of using OLE embedded objects in my applications many years ago.

Comment: Thanks rhsatrhs. Looks like using Notes C API is the only option.